# Best way to delete a django model instance after a certain date

Tags: python, django

I am writing a little app where the user creates an event and specifies the date that event will occur. After the event date has past, I want to delete that event instance. My current attempt is throwing a function that checks if the event should expire in the event page view. I am not sure whether the expiration_check function is checking in a correct way, nor am I sure whether just having a function in the view will event work.

Here is my view and expire function:

```
def event_page(request, name):
    event = Event.objects.get(name=name)

    check_expiration(event)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GuestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Guest = form.save(commit=False)
            Guest.event = event
            Guest.save()
            return redirect(event)
    else:
        form = GuestForm()
        return render(request, "event_page.html", {"form": form, "event": event, })


def check_expiration(event):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    if event.date < now: #if the event date has past
        event.delete()
```

I collect the date from the user and store it in a DateTime filed: date = models.DateField()

Let me know if any further details are needed. Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is your intention for the event to be deleted right after it has expired whether someone views the event page or not?

Comment: Your `check_expiration` function is fine, but calling it in the `event_page` function means expired events will stick around until after a user loads the `event_page` for one of them (imagine the user flow; probably pretty confusing!). See below for a different approach.

Answer (score 18):

If you're hosting your application on a UNIX platform (GNU/Linux, OSX, *etc.*), it's probably best to make use of `cron`, the generic system utility for running things periodically.

This requires implementing your expiry code as a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-management-commands/):

1. If you don't have any custom management commands already, create the following directory structure:

   ```
   yourapp/
     management/
        __init__.py (blank)
        commands/
          __init__.py (blank)
          expire_events.py
   ```
2. In `expire_events.py`, create a new class along the lines of the following:

   ```
   from django.core.management.base import NoArgsCommand

   class Command(NoArgsCommand):

       help = 'Expires event objects which are out-of-date'

       def handle_noargs(self):
           print Event.objects.filter(date__lt=datetime.datetime.now()).delete()
   ```
3. Now you should be able to run `./manage.py expire_events` and have any events with expiry dates in the past deleted.

To run this at regular intervals using `cron` (these instructions are for GNU/Linux but may well work on other UNIX variants), run `sudo crontab -e` and add the following line:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/your/django/app/manage.py expire_events
```

(this would run the task every 5 minutes; see [the crontab documentation](http://ss64.com/bash/crontab.html) for advice on specifying job run times)

Comment: Ok, I guess it wouldn't hurt to learn about this type of thing :) I am on heroku and they recommend this over cron: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler . Also, what about celery? http://celeryproject.org/

Comment: Yep, either of those would work (there's a section of the [celery docs on "periodic tasks"](http://packages.python.org/celery/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)). One caveat with celery is that you'd need `celerybeat` running all the time to kick off jobs.