# Delete an object automatically after specified time

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to delete an object after a specified time from the database.

Here's my Code:

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'code: ' + str(self.code)

    @property
    def deletes_in_ten_seconds(self):
        time = self.created_at + timedelta(seconds=10)
        query = Email.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if time > now():
            query.delete()
```

Yet it's not working. Do I have to call the delete method after a while somehow? I really don't have a clue. (new to django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `deletes_in_ten_seconds()` isn't ever called in your code, so the query isn't ever going to run.

Secondly, yes, you have to ask the database to delete your rows when it needs to happen, so you're going to need to schedule this (every so often) somehow. There are many ways to do it: from threads inside your python app to using functionality provided by the database.

Comment: Thank you. Just do you mind elaborating one of the ways to call the delete method? It would be really helpful if you could write the code example for it too.

Comment: Here, this question has you covered
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959866/how-to-delete-django-object-after-countdown

Comment: Oh appreciate 

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a scheduled job for this.

Maybe you'd like to use Celery to do this.

Documentation here: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'code: ' + str(self.code)

    @property
    def deletes_in_ten_seconds(self):
        time = self.created_at + timedelta(seconds=10)
        query = Email.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        
        # add this code
        while True:
           if time > now():
              query.delete()
              break
```

When `deletes_in_ten_seconds` is executed, the `if statement` is not satisfied and therefore it exits without further judgment. So you must add a `while loop`, to keep it running until `query.delete()` occurs.